# Altitude sensor for Raspberry Pi using only GPIO

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to get altitude data for a Raspberry Pi. I also need it to use only regular GPIO, and be relativity small.

I was thinking about an MLP311A5 with some sort of analog to PWM converter, but in that case it needs to be able to talk analog both ways (I believe). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Pls link to your MLP311A5, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at BME280 and BME680 devices? These use the I2C interface which is just gpio. As for ‘small’ what is small to you may not be small for me - specify a size. Same with ‘cheap’, ‘simple’ etc

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a digital sensor with an SPI  (can be bit-banged with 'regular GPIO') or I2C (available on the RPi, easy to enable) interface?

Comment: If you have GPIO(s) available then you can probably bit-bang the protocol for pretty much any easily available altimeter.

Comment: There is no sensor called MLP311A5. Do you mean MPL3115A2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a device such as the [MPL3115A2](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Pressure/MPL3115A2.pdf), which is a general-purpose pressure-derived altimeter, i2c interface, intended for drones with an accuracy of about a metre.  A number of IOT companies make breakout boards for it.

Here's a no-soldering [instructble](https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-MPL3115A2-Precision-Altimeter-Sensor--1/) using it with a Pi.  Another [shorter](http://www.pibits.net/code/raspberry-pi-and-mpl3115a2-pressure-sensor.php) one.